# Jest Snapshots fail on SVG props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jestjs, font-awesome

Jest snapshot test fail when including Fontawesome-React icon components.
I don't pass a `title` or `aria-labelledby` to the SVG components, and even when I do pass it those props, the snapshot continues to hash the props. Tests fail to pass since a new hash is generated in those two props every time the tests run.

`"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",`

`"jest": "^23.6.0",`

```
        <svg
    -     aria-labelledby="svg-inline--fa-title-y4Cv9dkIlhtu"
    +     aria-labelledby="svg-inline--fa-title-gIn5ZJBsxixz"
          className="svg-inline--fa fa-user-circle fa-w-16 fa-1x "
          color="whitesmoke"
          data-css-knsav2=""
          data-icon="user-circle"
          data-prefix="fas"
    @@ -23,11 +23,11 @@
          }
          viewBox="0 0 496 512"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <title
    -       id="svg-inline--fa-title-y4Cv9dkIlhtu"
    +       id="svg-inline--fa-title-gIn5ZJBsxixz"
            style={Object {}}
          >
            User Profile
          </title>
```

Comment: https://github.com/jest-community/jest-snapshots-svg ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our solution was to create a jest.mock for the svg components we were importing.
Ultimately, we don't want to test foreign libraries in our own tests,
so this was the accepted solution for us.

For example:

```
jest.mock('@materialui/icons', () => ({ 
    SomeIcon: () => <div>SomeIconHere</div>,
    // etc...
});
```

This helps keep our snapshot tests stable.

Answer (score 0):

People have been resolving this (it's kind of a hack) with overriding `Math.random`:

https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/issues/194